# When riding in the flight deck of a large airplane, why does it appear that the airplane moves slowly?

Tags: landing, airliner, human-factors

I recently rode in the jumpseat of an A330, and on approach, the visual impression of speed is very different from that of a small airplane or flight simulator.

Specifically, it appears that the airplane moves quite slowly and that the view to the outside is “zoomed in,” whereas in a small airplane or flight simulator, it appears “zoomed out.”

What causes this?

Comment: As Doug Henning used to say, "it's an illusion"...

Comment: Could it be the position - ie. jumpseat is back away from windows (narrower field of view), whereas flight sim it's pilot eye? or small plane you are right at the front of the plane?  And of course the audio possibly makes a difference too..

Comment: This question is about optical illusions, not aviation. as such it probably should be in the Biology stack exchange forum. Voting to close.

Comment: I actually have the opposite feeling, that on the jumpseat it actually goes faster than in the sim, talking for the 737/320 now, maybe A330, because sitting further AFT it can create that illusion I guess...